# JQuery datepicker close after first time selecting a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datepicker

I am facing issue with JQuery daterangepicker in my angular project. first time i select date and daterangepicker get close. and then again i press on date-picker field it gets fluctuate. immediately open and close daterangepicker and i m unable to select date.sometimes it does not even open the date picker.and sometime it opens more than 1 daterangepicker .

Expected Behaviour :

first time i open daterangepicker and select date, it should close after date selection.Again i can able to open daterangepicker and date can be change if required

datepicker.html

```
<li class="jp-calender-search col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group daterange-group">
    <label for="checkin-out" class="form-label jp-desktop-label">Booking Dates</label>

    <span (click)="uparrowImg();dropdownhideshow()" (focusout)="onDestinationFocusOut()" class="abcd" id="datesrangespick">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <input name="datefilter" required type="text" id="HotelsJP_HP_WS_Search_CheckIn_Out" class="form-control jp-home-input jp-search-cal"
            placeholder="Check-in - Check-out"  aria-label="checkin-out" readonly="readonly" aria-describedby="checkin-out" >
        <span class="datesac"></span>            

        <span class="jp-homecalendericon downarrowcal"></span>            
    </span>

    <span class="cm-icon icon-caldr jp-homepage-icon"></span>
    <span id="searchdateval" style="display: none">
        <label class="error" for="place" style="display: block;">Please select valid booking dates</label>
    </span>
    <span id="searchdatevalres" style="display: none">
        <label class="error" for="place" style="display: block;">No of nights more than 30 are not possible.</label>
    </span>

</div>
```

datepicker.ts

```
onDestinationFocusOut() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        console.log("in focus out--->", this.uparrrow);
        if (this.uparrrow == true) {
           // this.uparrrow = false;
            console.log('hide show')
            console.log(this.uparrrow)
            //  document.getElementById("hideshowdatepicker").style.display = 'none';


        } else {
            console.log(this.uparrrow,"else")

            //  document.getElementById("hideshowdatepicker").style.display = 'block';
            this.uparrrow = true;

        }

    }


}

uparrrow: boolean = false;
uparrowImg() {
    // console.log("in arrow change" + this.uparrrow);
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        let checkindate = <HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("HotelsJP_HP_WS_Search_CheckIn_Out"));
        // let iddatepicker= <HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("hideshowdatepicker"));
        if (this.uparrrow == true) {
            // this.uparrrow = false;
            console.log('hide show')
            $('.jp-homecalendericon').removeClass('uparrowcal');
            $('.jp-homecalendericon').addClass('downarrowcal');
            document.getElementById("hideshowdatepicker").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("dropbigdiv12").style.display = 'none';


            checkindate.blur();
        } else {
            $('.jp-homecalendericon').removeClass('downarrowcal');
            $('.jp-homecalendericon').addClass('uparrowcal');
            checkindate.focus();
            document.getElementById("hideshowdatepicker").style.display = 'block';
            this.uparrrow = true;
        }
    }


}


dropdownhideshow() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        if (this.uparrrow == true) {
            document.getElementById("dropbigdiv12").style.display = 'none';

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this link -> http://jsfiddle.net/ma3rR/403/

Comment: why there are 2 `="datesrangespick">`. is it included also in your code?

Comment: thanks, but already tried and no success

Comment: @Shizukura no its not included in my code. i was my mistake here that i resloved.